# Consulta en MYSQL DATETIME()

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Tengo una base de datos en la cual se almacenan los paquetes de unos clientes y la fecha de creación de dicho paquete.

Necesito sacar cuantos paquetes hace un cliente cada día en un mes.
He probado con

```
SELECT distinct fecha_creacion FROM paqueteria.paquetes
where remitente=73
and date(fecha_creacion) >= '2017-10-01'
and date(fecha_creacion) <='2017-10-30'
```

El problema es que *fecha_creacion* esta en un formato datetime AAAA-MM-DD HH-MM-SS y del mismo dia me saca varios registros pero con diferente hora

```
2017-10-02 13:57:34
2017-10-02 13:58:15
2017-10-03 14:58:32
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es hacer uso de la función [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(
    fecha_creacion,
    "%Y-%m-%d"
  ) fecha_creacion
FROM paquetes
WHERE
  remitente=73
AND
  fecha_creacion BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2017-10-31'
```

O bien la función [`DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date):

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT DATE(fecha_creacion) fecha_creacion
FROM paquetes
WHERE
  remitente=73
AND
  fecha_creacion BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2017-10-31'
```

Puedes comprobar su funcionamiento en esta versión en línea ([con `DATE_FORMAT`](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/haB8fhU6gGtJc4W8z2kY8X/2) y [con `DATE`](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/haB8fhU6gGtJc4W8z2kY8X/1)).

En ambos casos he usado el alias `fecha_creacion` para que el nombre del campo se mantenga el mismo aunque su contenido sea sólo año, mes y día.

Si quieres que te cuente el número de paquetes entonces debes usar `GROUP BY` en vez de `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT
  DATE(fecha_creacion) fecha_creacion,
  COUNT(*) numero
FROM paquetes
WHERE
  fecha_creacion BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2017-10-31'
GROUP BY DATE(fecha_creacion)
```

Si quieres evitarte el `DATE(fecha_creacion)` entonces debes cambiar el alias para evitar confusión con el nombre del campo (que tiene preferencia):

```
SELECT
  DATE(fecha_creacion) fecha,
  COUNT(*) numero
FROM paquetes
WHERE
  fecha_creacion BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2017-10-31'
GROUP BY fecha
```

Ten en cuenta que la consulta [no está optimizada porque ni `fecha` ni `DATE(fecha_creacion)` son índices](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-optimization.html).

Answer (score 4):

Yo lo haría sencillamente así:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
    total, remitente , 
    DATE(fecha_creacion) fecha 
FROM paquetes_20171025 
WHERE remitente=73 AND fecha_creacion BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2017-10-31'
GROUP BY fecha;
```

### Prueba de concepto

**<kbd>[VER DEMO](http://rextester.com/BZY25274)</kbd>**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS paquetes_20171025 
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    remitente INT,  fecha_creacion DATETIME
)ENGINE=INNODB;


INSERT INTO paquetes_20171025 (remitente, fecha_creacion)
    VALUES 
    (73,'2016-10-02 13:57:34'),
    (73,'2016-10-02 13:58:15'),
    (73,'2016-10-03 14:58:32'),
    (73,'2017-10-02 13:57:34'),
    (73,'2017-10-02 13:58:15'),
    (73,'2017-10-03 14:58:32'),
    (73,'2017-10-04 13:57:34'),
    (73,'2017-10-04 13:58:15'),
    (73,'2017-10-05 14:58:32'),
    (74,'2017-10-02 13:57:34'),
    (74,'2017-10-02 13:58:15'),
    (75,'2017-10-03 14:58:32'),
    (76,'2017-10-04 13:57:34'),
    (77,'2017-10-04 13:58:15'),
    (77,'2017-10-05 14:58:32')
;

-- Datos de prueba 


SELECT COUNT(*) 
    total, remitente , 
    DATE(fecha_creacion) fecha 
FROM paquetes_20171025 
WHERE remitente=73 AND fecha_creacion BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2017-10-31'
GROUP BY fecha;
```

---

### Resultado:

```
total   remitente    fecha
2       73           02.10.2017 00:00:00
1       73           03.10.2017 00:00:00
2       73           04.10.2017 00:00:00
1       73           05.10.2017 00:00:00
```

Comment: Ciertamente @OscarGarcia, el `remitente` ya estaba en el `WHERE`, buen punto.

Answer (score 0):

Para que te muestre el numero de paquetes ejecutaría la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT DATE(fecha_creacion) as fecha_creacion, count(*) Paquetes
FROM paqueteria.paquetes
WHERE
  remitente=73
AND
  date(fecha_creacion) BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2017-10-31'
group by fecha_creacion;
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos

Comment: Prueba la consulta, no funciona por tener dos `WHERE` ([enlace](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/haB8fhU6gGtJc4W8z2kY8X/3)). Además el group by tal y como lo tienes tampoco funciona por lo que pongo en mi respuesta, mira este otro ejemplo ([enlace](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/haB8fhU6gGtJc4W8z2kY8X/4)).

Comment: Gracias por la aclaratoria, es probable que se deba a la versión de Mysql y el WHERE adicional fue un error de tipeo jeje. yo utilizo esta misma consulta para obtener el numero de gestiones que se realiza a un cliente por día y me funciona sin problemas. El DISTINCT se puede eliminar pero igual la consulta se ejecuta. Saludos

Comment: ¿Has mirado mis enlaces? No, no funciona ni bajando a una [versión de MySQL 5.5](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/haB8fhU6gGtJc4W8z2kY8X/5) ni subiendo a la [versión MySQL 8.0](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/haB8fhU6gGtJc4W8z2kY8X/6).

Comment: Muchas gracias a los dos, me ha salido sin problemas, lo necesitaba para hacer una media de paquetes al mes. Saludos

Comment: Claro hay que eliminar el WHERE adicional que se me paso tipeando, igual ya edite la respuesta y funciona. Muchas gracias por la corrección. Ya Hayber resolvió.

Comment: No @Kerepakupai, no basta con quitar el WHERE, no obtienes los resultados correctos. No has mirado ninguno de mis enlaces para comprobar que no funcionan bien ni has leído mi respuesta. Cuando lo hagas quizá entiendas por qué no te funciona la consulta que has creado.

Comment: @OscarGarcia si te fijas en la respuesta y analizas un poco, el problema esta en que esa herramienta que utilizas para probar solo crea una tabla y esta no esta asociada a ningún esquema, es imposible que la tabla no pertenezca a ninguna base de datos (para probar esta bien), pero si lees bien la pregunta de hayber el esquema es "paqueteria" lo cual agregue en la respuesta ya que seria la forma correcta de realizar la consulta, solo elimina el esquema y te funcionara sin problemas. Nuevamente gracias por intentar explicarme pero también hay que analizar un poco no solo copiar y probar.

Comment: @Kerepakupai, lo del esquema deberías pensártelo un poco. Te explico cuál es el problema de tu consulta: **el campo `fecha_creacion` tiene preferencia sobre el alias `fecha_creacion`** que has creado con el operador opcional `AS` cuando usas `GROUP BY`. Por ese motivo agrupará por el campo original y, al tener hora, minutos y segundos, la función `COUNT` siempre contará 1 aunque el operador `DISTINCT` "se coma" los elementos repetidos con misma fecha y diferentes horas.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo convierte la fecha con Cast así:

```
SELECT fecha_creacion, remitente, count(*) FROM paqueteria.paquetes
where remitente=73
and Cast(fecha_creacion as Date) Between '2017-10-01'
and '2017-10-30'
Group by fecha_creacion
Order by 1
```

No lo probé, lo escribí y nada más.